# Confused Regarding PyTorch GRU Docs

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch, lstm

This may be too basic of a question, but what do the docs mean by the input to the GRU needs to be 3 dimensional? The GRU docs for PyTorch state:

> input of shape (seq_len, batch, input_size): tensor containing the
> features of the input sequence. The input can also be a packed
> variable length sequence. See
> torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence() for details.

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html

Let us say I am trying to predict the next # in a sequence and have the following dataset:

```
n, label
1, 2
2, 3
3, 6
4, 9
...
```

If I window the data using the prior 2 inputs for consideration when guessing the next, the dataset becomes:

```
t-2, t-1, t, label
na, na, 1, 2
na, 1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3, 6
2, 3, 4, 10
...
```

where t-x just represents using an input value from a prior time step.

So, when creating a sequential loader, it should create the following tensor for the line 1,2,3,6:

```
inputs: tensor([[1,2,3]]) #shape(1,3)
labels: tensor([[6]])     #shape(1,1)
```

I currently understand the input shape as (# batches, # features per batch)
and the output shape as (# batches, # output features per batch)

My question is, should that input tensor actually look like:

```
tensor([[[1],[2],[3]]])
```

Which represents (# batches, #prior inputs to consider, #features per input)

I guess I am better trying to understand why the input to a GRU has 3 dimensions in PyTorch. What does that 3rd dimension fundamentally represent? And if I have a transformed dataset like above, how to properly pass it to the model.

Edit:
So the pattern present is:

```
1 + 1 = 2
2 + 1 = 3
3 + 2 + 1 = 6
4+ 3 + 2 + 1 = 10
```

I want it where t-2, t-1, and t represent the features at each time step used to help guess. For example, at every point in time there could be 2 features. The dimensions would be (1 batch size, 3 timesteps, 2 features).

My question is wether the GRU takes a flattened input:

```
(1 batch size, 3 time steps * 2 features per time step)
```

or the unflattened input:

```
(1 batch size, 3 time steps, 2 features per timestep)
```

I am currently under the impression that it is the 2nd input, but would like to check my understanding.

Comment: Can you show me how you would represent this sequence with 3 two-feature vectors: `[1, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Essentially, the sequence length of 3 means that the input to the system needs to be: [[[1],[2],[3]], [[2], [3], [4]]] for a batch size of 2, sequence length of 3, and feature input per time step of 1. Essentially each sequence is an input at some time t to consider.

Comment: `input_size=0`, but I honestly doubt your model will be able to learn without having encoded your data. Look: `4` > `3` > `2` > `1`, there order in your inputs, `4` the biggest input will take precedence over all other.

Answer (score 3):

The [`nn.GRU`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html) module works like other PyTorch RNN modules. It takes a three-dimensional tensor `(seq_len, batch, input_size)` or `(batch, seq_len, input_size)` if the argument `batch_first` is set to `True`. I think the last dimension is what's bothering you.

You explained you have your sequences set up like:

| t-2 | t-1 | t | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| na | na | 1 | 2 |
| na | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 10 |

What you are missing is your input encoding: how will you represent your predictions and your labels? Feeding integers like this will not work right. What you probably need is to convert your data into one-hot-encodings.

Imagine having *10* different labels, i.e. you vocabulary is made up of *10* elements. Converting to one-hot-encodings is a straight forward process. Take a vector of zeros whose length is the vocabulary size and put a *1* at the index corresponding to a particular label.

The vocaulary size would in turn be... `input_size`. Given a `label`, this would look like:

```
encoding = torch.zeros(input_size)
encoding[label] = 1
```

| label | one-hot-encoding |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `[1,0,0,..., 0, 0]` |
| `1` | `[0,1,0,..., 0, 0]` |
| ... | ... |
| `9` | `[0,0,0,..., 0, 1]` |

Therefore, your training point (*input sequence*: `1, 2, 3`, *label*: `6`) would translate to (*input sequence*: `[[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]`, *label*: `6`). Which is two-dimensional, added the extra dimension for the batch (see first §), this makes three.

I intentionnaly left the label as it is because it's common for PyTorch loss functions (such as [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss)) to require an index instead of a one-hot-encoding for the target (// label).

Comment: I edited my question to better illustrate my confusion.

Comment: I think you didn't quite understand what I tried to explain here, you have to encode your input. The encoding will determine your `input_size` i.e. `dim=2` of your GRU input. Only then will you choose your sequence length, here your sequence is `[t-2, t-1, t]` `seq_length=3` which you will have to encode into a shape `(3, 10)`. In turn, **your GRU input has three dimensions**. Please explain what's bothering you, or if some parts appear unclear.

Comment: I figured it out. Essentially, the sequence length of.3 means that the input to the system needs to be:

[[[1],[2],[3]], [[2], [3], [4]]] for a batch size of 2, sequence length of 3, and feature input per time step of 1.